# custom markers with icon google maps flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

Is there a way in Flutter like a package to create custom google maps markers with icons in them?
I don't mean using images as markers, but instead put icons inside the default marker as in this google maps screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You meant using material icons or the class IconData?, try this [post](https://medium.com/@JBXBergDev/how-to-use-googlemap-markers-with-flutter-material-icons-38c4c975e928)

Comment: please check this package it might help full -> https://pub.dev/packages/custom_map_markers